# Scheme function definition

Tags: scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

I have been reading "The Little Schemer" in my spare time and trying to experiment with the syntax and I've come across a syntax issue I can't wrap my head around.  I have a script that looks like this:

```
;;;; Chapter 2 examples
;;; Note: run this file with 'mit-scheme --quiet < c2.scm'

;; You can define variables using the "define" function
(define my-favorite-number 13)

;; You can define strings using double-quotes
(define my-favorite-color "green")

;; you define functions with lambdas.  Functions auto return their last line
(define my-favorites
  (lambda (color number)
    (string-append "My favorite color is " color " and my favorite number is " number)))

; display will print
(display
 (my-favorites my-favorite-color (number->string my-favorite-number)))

; and newline prints a newline
(newline)
```

This works perfectly when run.

Underneath that, I have a little more:

```
(define greet
  (lambda (name)
    (string-append "Hello, " name)))

(display (greet "World"))
```

When running this file, I can not seem to get "Hello, World"to print.  The first display works beautifully, but the second one does not do anything, and I can't explain why.  At first I thought this might have something to do with how scheme runs in an interactive environment normally, so I stripped out the first block of code, but still nothing happens.

If I load the file in an interactive session, the "greet" function works perfectly, so I think this must be something odd about the display function.

Can anyone explain why my first display works but my second one does not?

[Here is a github link to the exact file](https://github.com/ZacheryPD/LearningLisp/blob/master/c2.scm)

Comment: I'd try this is a different environment. I don't know Scheme, but the two examples look fairly equivalent. Maybe restart your REPL or whatever you're running this in.

Comment: Output for `c2.scm` is `"My favorite color is green and my favorite number is 13\nHello, World"` when running in [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/)

Comment: A guess: try to call `(flush-output-port)` at the end of the file...

Comment: @RainerJoswig That function gives me an "Unbound variable: flush-output-port" error, but it did cause the final "hello, world" to print, so I tried something strange and put a `(newline)` at the end of the file, and now it behaves as expected.  I think there may be some interaction between `newline` and `display` that I don't understand.

Comment: You might want to check which version of MIT Scheme you are using. There are similar functions to flush-output-port - check the manual of the version you are using. The output stream may be buffered. newline may just call something like flush-output-port to ensure that buffered output is forced to be delivered.

Comment: It works for me when I run `mit-scheme --quiet --no-init-file <  c2.scm`. This quits Scheme after the execution and will force flush. The terminal you use might apply buffers based on the interactive nature of the command, but most shells are line buffered so that you don't see anything until a linefeed or program end. (which has nothing to do with Scheme and everything to do with your shell) How do you run it?

Comment: I am primarily running this on MacOS in terminal.  @Sylwester's addition of `--no-init-file` is exactly what I was missing.  If you submit that as an answer I will accept it 